# How to change empty event selection content in fullcalendar v5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to display different content in empty timegrid event and and already rendered events.I used  `eventContent` but it changes content in both of them.

```js
eventContent: function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        var etitle = ''
        if (event.event.title) {
            etitle = `<label title="` + event.event.title + `" class="bg-b-warning event-lbl-shadow rounded py-1 px-2 text-light " style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;">` + event.event.title + `</label>`
        } else {
            etitle = ''
        }
        return {
            html: `
        <div class="st_event_container overflow-hidden w-100 p-2 row mx-auto">
            <div class="col p-0 "><label class="bg-light event-lbl-shadow rounded py-1 px-2 text-dark mr-1">`+ event.timeText + `</label></div><div class="col p-0 mb-1">` + etitle + `</div>
            
        
        </div>` }
    },
```

Screenshot for clearity (**blue** events are already rendered, **semitransparent** is empty grid selection)

Here displayed 4 resources, and set on **today** view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is happening when the `selectMirror` option is set to `true`. (I am just putting that clarification there for future readers, as the use of that option isn't mentioned in the question, but there's no way this behaviour would happen if it wasn't set.)

There is an easy way to differentiate between normal events and these "mirror" events - if you inspect the information object supplied to the eventContent callback (and which in your code you are logging in the console) you'll see there is an `isMirror` property which is only set true when the element being rendered represents a mirror selection.

So you can just write something like this:

```
eventContent: function(info)
{
  if (info.isMirror == true)
  {
    //do whatever you want to do for mirror events here
  }
  else
  {
    //do whatever you want to do for regular events here
  }
}
```

(N.B. Code quality note: In my example I renamed the parameter to "info" because "event" is a misnomer - the event data is stored in a property within the info object, and writing something like event.event.title is clearly ridiculous, and because isMirror isn't a property of an event, so writing `event.isMirror` might appear misleading. Using the wrong name for something also makes your code harder to understand when you come back to it later.)